# How can I make a "Wait, it's processing ..!" system?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code:

```js
function sleep (time) {
   return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));
}

$("body").on('click', '.fa-check', function(e) {

  // sleep() emulates a short waiting  time as ajax's request
  sleep(1000).then(() => {
     $('.fa-check').not(this).removeClass('checked');
     $(this).toggleClass('checked');
  });

});
```

```css
.fa-check {
  color: #aaa;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.fa-check.checked {
  color: #44b449;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/9e9ad91d21.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>answer1</p>
<i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<hr>
<p>answer2</p>
<i class="fa fa-check checked" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<hr>
<p>answer3</p>
<i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

As I've commented in my codes, I've emulated a short waiting time as ajax's request. Now I want to show the user *"it's processing"* when he clicks on one of those checked-icons. I can use a png like this under the icon: [image]

But I want to do that by turning that checked-icon off/on as waiting *(it is processing)* time. Currently when I click on a checked-icon, nothing happens, and then after `1 sec` the green color changes. Now I want to do something in this `1 sec` to show the user *"the system is working, please wait .."*.

Turning that checked-icon off/on can be a good idea. Anybody knows how can I do that?

**EDIT:** I don't want to use any image. I just want to change the color of that checked-icon. Like a lamp that turns on and turns off.

Comment: What is expected effect? At click on `.fa-check` the clicked element should have `checked` `className` added, which changes color to green, then after one second the element should toggle the added `className`?

Comment: @guest271314 1. user clicks on one of those icons. 2. that icon starts winking. 3. after a while *(1sec in this case)*  the blinking stops. 4. then `checked` className adds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. user clicks on one of those icons. 2. that icon starts winking. 3. after a while (1sec in this case) the blinking stops. 4. then checked
>      className adds.

You can use `.fadeToggle()` with duration set to `1000` / `x` where `x` is number of times `.fadeToggle()` should be called to simulate "wink" or blinking effect during `sleep()` call

```js
function sleep (time) {
   return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));
}

function blink (time) {
  $(this).fadeToggle(time, function() {
    if (++n < t) {
      return blink.call(this, time)
    } else {
      n = 0;
    }
  })
}

var duration = 1000;
var n = 0;
var t = 10;
var blinks = duration / t;

$("body").on('click', '.fa-check', function(e) {
  // sleep() emulates a short waiting  time as ajax's request
  $.when(blink.call(this, blinks), sleep(duration))
  .then(() => {
     $('.fa-check').not(this).removeClass('checked');
     $(this).toggleClass('checked');
  });

});
```

```css
.fa-check {
  color: #aaa;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.fa-check.checked {
  color: #44b449;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/9e9ad91d21.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>answer1</p>
<i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<hr>
<p>answer2</p>
<i class="fa fa-check checked" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<hr>
<p>answer3</p>
<i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Comment: Just two questions: 1. why did you pass `time` parameter to the `blink` function but never use it? 2. why did you define `n` and `t` variables and never use them?

Comment: `n` and `t` are used, will update post to use `time` at `blink` instead of `duration / t`, or, rather, define `blinks` as `duration / t`.

Comment: Yeah I'm seeing it .. thank you. it works and all fine .. just for your information, `duration` isn't a constant variable, it's actually a simulator for an ajax request. I used it to show you what I'm looking for exactly .. I mean there isn't any sleep function in my real codes at all.

Comment: @stack _"it's actually a simulator for an ajax request. I used it to show you what I'm looking for exactly .. I mean there isn't any sleep function in my real codes at all."_ Yes. You could probably utilize `Promise.race()` for this, to prevent animation continuing when `$.ajax()` completes; although you could call `.stop()` on the currently animating element as well.

Comment: I guess you are the person who is able to write an answer for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38687453/how-can-i-calculate-the-time-waiting-of-a-ajaxs-request) pretty similar question. If you have some free time, please take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

This is honestly quite easy, make a div which only has the loading image.

```
<div id="loading_image">
<img src="loader.gif">
</div>
```

Now display it as soon as the jQuery request is begun, and hide it when it's completed

```
$("body").on('click', '.fa-check', function(e) {
  //show the loader
  $("#loading_image").show();
  // sleep() emulates a short waiting  time as ajax's request
  sleep(1000).then(() => {
     $('.fa-check').not(this).removeClass('checked');
     $(this).toggleClass('checked');
     //hide loader now
     $("#loading_image").hide();
  });

});
```

Comment: Well I think I didn't ask my question clear. I don't want to use any image. I just want to change the color of that checked-icon. Like a lamp that turns on and turns off.

Comment: @stack
Do you have a live example of what you want done?

Comment: @guest271314's answer is a live example `:-)` ... anyway thanks for your solution.