# How can I calculate the time a request takes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

**This is what I'm trying to do:**

> 1.user clicks on one of those checked icons. 2. that icon starts winking. 3. after a while (the time of request takes) the blinking stops. 4. then checked className adds

**Here is my code which works as well:**

```js
function sleep (time) {
   return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));
}

function blink (time) {
  $(this).fadeToggle(time, function() {
    if (++n < t) {
      return blink.call(this, time)
    } else {
      n = 0;
    }
  })
}

var duration = 1000;
var n = 0;
var t = 10;
var blinks = duration / t;

$("body").on('click', '.fa-check', function(e) {
  // sleep() emulates a short waiting  time as ajax's request
  $.when(blink.call(this, blinks), sleep(duration))
  .then(() => {
     $('.fa-check').not(this).removeClass('checked');
     $(this).toggleClass('checked');
  });

});
```

```css
.fa-check {
  color: #aaa;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.fa-check.checked {
  color: #44b449;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/9e9ad91d21.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>answer1</p>
<i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<hr>
<p>answer2</p>
<i class="fa fa-check checked" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<hr>
<p>answer3</p>
<i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

As you see, I've defined a function named `sleep()` which emulates the **waiting time** of such an ajax request. Now I want to use real ajax codes. Here is what I've tried so far:

```
function blink (time) {
  $(this).fadeToggle(time, function() {
    if (++n < t) {
      return blink.call(this, time)
    } else {
      n = 0;
    }
  })
}

$("body").on('click', '.fa-check', function(e) {

blink(); // start winking

    $.ajax({
        url :  urlhref,
        type : 'GET',
        dataType : 'JSON',
        success : function (acceptedanswering_system) {              
            if(acceptedanswering_system.error_msg){
                alert(acceptedanswering_system.error_msg);          

            } else {
                alert('done');
            }

            // some other codes here

        }
    });

});
```

**My question:** I don't have a specific time that I initialize it as `duration` variable. Because the time of an ajax request isn't constant, it depends on the server and etc .. so how can I implement a real ajax code instead of that emulator function?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Obviously you can't calculate the time a request takes. You don't know future. You can predict it somewhat but I don't see why you need this to begin with?

Comment: @freakish This is what I'm trying to do: 1.user clicks on one of those checked icons. 2. that icon starts winking. 3. after a while (the time of request takes) the blinking stops. 4. then checked className adds.

Comment: Do steps 3 and 4 in success (or complete) handler. What's the issue?

Comment: @freakish When I cannot stop blinking ...

Comment: The problem is with your `blink` function. It does not allow stopping (and once called it leaks memory). Plus it fails because `this` inside a `fadeToggle` handler is not the same as `$(this)`. You have to rewrite it to something else, some object supporting `blinker.start()` and `blinker.stop()` which then you will call before and after the request respectively.

Comment: @freakish Well I'm trying to implement what you said .. but honestly I failed. Can you please write an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, judging from comments what you actually need is a better blinker. Have a look at this:

```
var Blinker = function(el, time) {
    this.el = el;
    this.time = time;
    this.running = false;
    this._fader = this._fade.bind(this);
};
Blinker.prototype = {
    _fade: function() {
        if (!this.running) {
            return;
        }
        this.el.fadeToggle(this.time, this._fader);
    },
    start: function() {
        this.running = true;
        this._fader();
    },
    stop: function() {
        this.running = false;
    }
};
```

and usage:

```
$("body").on('click', '.fa-check', function(e) {
    var blinker = new Blinker($(this), 100);
    blinker.start();
    $.ajax({
        // some other code
        complete: function() {
            blinker.stop();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Just two question: 1. why did you pass `time` parameter to that function? that's the time of what? I mean what's `100` in this `new Blinker($(this), 100);`? 2. what's that underline `_` in the beginning of `fade:` ?

Comment: `time` is a time it takes to fade (e.g. blink frequency). Underscore `_` is just a naming convention for "private" functions. Just to mark that you should not use `_fade` directly.

Comment: I see .. Just can you please tell me why did you define a object to do that? I guess you could define a simple function instead .. Am I right?

Comment: No, because you have to have at least `running` variable which is (logically) a state of a blinker. You could do that with global `running` variable but that's just aweful and might lead to tricky issues.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you wan't to predict the time it takes to talk to a remote server. My answer would be, you can't (unless you are in a very specific environment, but the answer then would be, you shouldn't).

There is no way of telling how long a request is going to take. This is because of the very nature of the internet, different routes, different loads on different aspects of the server etc...

What you actually wan't to do is use a callback to do something whenever the server responds. This callback can be use to stop the blinking icon.

This is perfectly possible to do in the success callback of $.ajax.

Try to use callback or promises for async data. Polling for updates can be considered an anti pattern.